# Static methods in static class started from more threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, static

I have static class with 2 static methods, I call them both in different threads and they fill data to static properties. The problem is that one method takes longer to finish than the other, for reason which I don't know, when I call one method I wait until the other is finished (it's called sooner). I want it to be processed without any dependency to each other.

Is the reason that it is static class and you can call just one method in one time?

If yes its possible to make it somehow or what is the best solution.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: Unortunatly im on mobile phone but its mutch more teoretic question than practic. I just simply need to know if methods in static class can be processed at same time.

Comment: The problem is not that the class is static. It's perfectly possible to have multiple threads calling methods in the same static class. We need to see code to diagnose your actual problem. When you're at a computer, can you get an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) together?

Comment: Than can you suggest me why it waits until each other to finish when they are not logicaly related?

Comment: No, I cannot. There's nothing to go on. As I said, **we need to see code**.

Comment: I will post when i will be at computer for sure. The thing is that i put break point at the end of the one which takes longer and i call different method in this static class from main thread but nothing happend until that brakepoint is hit. Even when i press f11 in VS im not going inside umtil that one is done.

Comment: If you have two methods running on diferent threads manipulating shared variables then when one method is in the critical region(where it maniupulates shared variables) the other MUST wait. It doesn't make a difference if they are static or instance methods